# Modifiler Boolean doesn't work. Why?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, transforms

My problem is that I want to delete part of an object on an object using another object and a Boolean modifier, but for some reason all this does not work correctly, below I left a link to a video in Google Drive. If there are not enough explanations, then don’t hesitate to ask. I really need your help.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_vDS4YPluWkI_LytreJZ01ac_p-nK93/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, under Solvert Options try the Hole Tolerant option, and also try the Fast option, if it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked both objects are manifold using the 3D-Print tool? You could also poke the cylinder cap face incase that's causing issues